# Receiving output "called with incorrect property" when I write a figure by using matplotlib and also by other tools

Tags: python, matplotlib, macos-catalina

By matplotlib I created a figure which describes sine curve and I received following standard outputs when I clicked the figure and terminal. The output figure seems correct.

The code is this;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Then I got this;

```
2020-07-30 00:23:41.170 python[22052:178325] imkxpc_getApplicationProperty:reply: called with incorrect property value 4, bailing.
2020-07-30 00:23:41.170 python[22052:178325] Text input context does not respond to _valueForTIProperty:
```

My environment is Python 3.8.3, conda 4.8.3 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

I find similar questions(like https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/matplotlib-users-called-with-incorrect-property-value-and-text-input-context-does-not-respond-to-valuefortiproperty-message/20871), but I can't find the solution.

I find that this also occurs when I write figure by gnuplot and ROOT. So I think this problem is not from matplotlib itself.

Any ideas to solve this problem? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your Conda environment?

Comment: I installed Anaconda-Navigator 1.9.12 and I got conda from this. (I'm newbie for programming so I do not understand what you wanna know.) Is this sufficient or should I list all of the contents of base environment which I get by type 'conda list' ?

Comment: Using `conda list` would be a good idea. Before that, though, you should create a separate environment, instead of using base.

Comment: I also had this error when running an ElectronJS app from terminal. I wonder if the problem is related to the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the Input Sources to English - ABC solves the problem. You can change the Input Sources from macOS System Preferences - Keyboard. Add or change the Input Source to English - ABC from Input Sources tab.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Are you sure this is what to OP meant?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! My MacBook is for Japanese and when I change the setting for Keyboards as you said there is no error and the problem is solved, but I don't know why this error happens....